# Prove that supremum of one function of $x$ is less than or equal to another function of $x$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $f,g:X\to\mathbb{R}$ with g bounded above and $f(x)<g(x)$ for all $x \in X$. Prove that $sup(f) \leq sup(g)$.

Also is it necessarily true that $sup(f) < sup(g)$?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Well if $f(x) \lt g(x)$ for all $x \in X$ then I think it should be obvious that the $sup(g)$ would be greater than $sup(f)$ but I'm not sure how to prove it and also I can't really see how the two suprema could be equal to one another if $g(x)$ is always greater than $f(x)$

Comment: Is $\sup(g)$ an upper bound for $f(X)$?

Comment: I think so. I think $sup(g)$ is an upper bound for $f(X)$ but I don't think that $sup(g)$ is equal to $sup(f)$

Comment: What is the relation between an upper bound of a set and its supremum??

Comment: An upper bound of a set will always be greater than or equal to the supremum right?

Comment: Good! so now what should the relation between $\sup f$ and $\sup g$ which is an upper bound of $f$ be?

Comment: $sup(g) \geq sup(f)$ for all $x$. Sorry I'm not very good with supremum/infimum questions

Comment: Never mind! You just needed to be steered in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both $f,g$ are bounded above so $\sup f,\sup g$ exist.

Since $f<g\le\sup g,\sup g$ is an upper bound for $f(X)$. Thus $\sup f\le\sup g$.

It is not necessary that $\sup f<\sup g$. Take, for example, $g(x)=k,f(x)=k-1/x,X=\Bbb R^+$. $g$ is bounded above by $k,f<g$ over $\Bbb R^+$ but $\sup g=\sup f=k$.